# Translate curl to python

Tags: python, curl

I have a curl request that works:

```
curl "https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/candidates/search.json?query=Wilson" 
-H "X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"
```

How can I translate this into Python? I tried the following:

```
payload = {'X-API-Key': 'myapikey'}
r = requests.get("https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/candidates/search.json?query=Wilson", params = payload)
```

Then, I got:

```
>>> print(r.url)
https://api.propublica.org/campaign-finance/v1/2016/candidates/search.json?query=Wilson&X-API-Key=myapikey
>>> r.text
u'{"message": "Forbidden"}'
```

Comment: Params are get params, you want headers: `r = requests.get(url, headers={'X-API-Key': 'myapikey'})`

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: Remark to the folks who marked this as duplicate: It is not duplicate! The OP does not ask how to send headers (as in the other question) but has an issue that can be solved by sending headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to translate your `curl` work to `python` will be to use [`pycurl`](http://pycurl.io/) instead of `requests`.

Your `Forbidden` issue, however, does not depend on using `requests` or `pycurl`. It comes from sending the `X-API-Key` as query parameters instead of sending it as header (as you did in the `curl` call).

Comment: Yes-- sending a header instead of a query parameter did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
import urllib2
url = your_url
payload = {'X-API-Key': 'myapikey'}
req = Request(url, payload, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
open = urlopen(req)
```

after this you can use whatever way you want to print. Hope this works for you.